# Open source backgammon in VB.NET/C#/WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, open-source

I'm looking for sample source for backgammon in VB.NET or C#, preferably using WPF.  What existing open source projects implement backgammon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set a rather high bar for your expectations.

The only open-source implementation I'm aware of is [GNU Backgammon](http://www.gnubg.org), which is written in C.  You should be able to port it to C#, but it wouldn't be very straightforward.

Other hits on Google appear to be those "meta-search" sites that just reflect your search terms back to you but don't have any useful information.

Comment: there is no sample code on c# or vb.net?

Comment: No, nor is it particularly surprising.  Backgammon isn't a particularly popular board game in most areas.  C# and WPF are not very widely used for games.  (not impossible, just not that common)  And even if someone had written a Backgammon game in C#/WPF, the odds of them releasing the source are even smaller.